# Insert multiple records into an table based on condition

Tags: sql-server

I have main table called `customer` where columns

```
MainCustID   AssocativeCustID
11           22
33           33
45           56
38           90
56           1234
356          356
```

Now I need to insert this value records to one more table based on the condition

- if `MainCustID` and `AssocativeCustID` are the same, then only 1 entry is to go into one more table called `collection` (that is the `MainCustID` entry)
- if `MainCustID` and `AssocativeCustID` are different, then 2 entries will go into table called `collection` (`MainCustID` and `AssocativeCustID`)

How can I achieve this concept?

I know this can be done based on cursors, is there any other way that we can achieve this.

Comment: In you second case where are the two entries coming from? one from the first table and the other entry where does it come? do you mean leave the entry form the second table `collection` and add the other entry from the first table `customer`??

Answer (score 2):

You could break it into three sub-tasks:

```
insert into Collection
    select MainCustID
    from Customer
    where MainCustID = AssocativeCustID;
insert into Collection
    select MainCustID
    from Customer
    where MainCustID <> AssocativeCustID;
insert into Collection
    select AssocativeCustID
    from Customer
    where MainCustID <> AssocativeCustID;
```

1. First insert all `MainCustID` where it's equal to the `AssocativeCustID`
2. Then all `MainCustID` where it's unequal to the `AssocativeCustID`
3. Then the other side, all `AssocativeCustID` where it's unequal to `MainCustID`

Here's a **demo**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60026/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of **cursor** you need to run these two insert queries:-

```
insert into collection values (select MainCustId from customer where MainCustID = AssocativeCustID);

insert into collection values (select MainCustId,AssocativeCustID from customer where MainCustID <> AssocativeCustID);
```